# What is the main rule to recognize significant column number in every page size?

Tags: multicol

How the multicol package measures the number of columns that can exist in each context? From 1 to 6 column, the package acts normally, but after 6 the tex engine produces the error *Dimension too large. H*. According the package document, the maximum number for column is 20.

```
\documentclass[5pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    showframe,
    margin=0.5cm,
    noheadfoot,
    nomarginpar,
    landscape,
    a0paper
}
\usepackage[debugshow]{multicol}
\setlength\premulticols{6\baselineskip}
\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}
\usepackage{spverbatim}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{6}
Hello, world!
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: landscape a0 is pretty large, probably the  package could try harder to avoid TeX's fixed dimen arithmetic limits, but it has to make a single column (before column breaking) so colnumber*\textheight. You could use a1 rather than a0 and scale.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The package has to make a single column (before column breaking) so colnumber*\textheight which is larger than `\maxdimen` here.

You could use a4 rather than a0 and scale.

```
\mag4000
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    showframe,
    margin=0.124cm,
    noheadfoot,
    nomarginpar,
    landscape,
    a4paper
}
\usepackage[debugshow]{multicol}
\setlength\premulticols{6\baselineskip}
\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}
\usepackage{spverbatim}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{2.25}{3}\selectfont
\begin{multicols}{20}
Hello, world!
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Makes a 20 column A0 document. pdfinfo reports:

```
$ pdfinfo file.pdf 
Creator:        TeX
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.24
CreationDate:   Wed Jan  4 14:16:25 2023 GMT
ModDate:        Wed Jan  4 14:16:25 2023 GMT
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      3367.56 x 2381.1 pts (A0)
Page rot:       0
File size:      40522 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! You really save us a lot of time. Is it possible not only font but also all other object and stuff ,for example tcolorbox, become scaled automatically?

Comment: yes it should all just work, just use quarter size lengths everywhere @Russel

Comment: @Russel which means I should have used `\setlength\columnseprule{.1pt}` or the rules would be a bit thick printed to A0